# select default value for drop down list and radio group in app-maker

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

For the app I'm building on Google App Maker I was asked to set default value for my dropdown list and my radio group , and it seems nearly impossible to do it , any ideas how to do it ? (default value and not Null item because the null item is not allowed in my case )
the value of the dropdown and radio group it a query parameter and not a datasource feild

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use the **onAttach** event handler?

You can set your widget onAttach even logic like this:

```
widget.value = "My default value";
```

See below:
[image]

I suggest you to go over the **[widgets logic documentation](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/logic#Events)** to comprehend more about how to achieve this type of things. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this help?

The below can be found by going to Data> Datasource>  Fields> String Field> Advanced.
[image]

Comment: No unfortunately because in my case the value of the drop down and ratio groupe is a query parameter and not a datasource field