# Appmaker fill a textbox with a default value in a create form

Tags: default-value, google-app-maker

In a create form, I want the textbox being filled with some default value :
For example 
- the date with the current date
- the price with the listprice outof the db, but so that the user can change it

I was not able to figure out where to do that

Comment: It would also interest me being able to set a value form another element on the page (textbox with another source for example)

Comment: I have answered a simiilar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51383918/select-default-value-for-drop-down-list-and-radio-group-in-app-maker/51384856#51384856, check if that helps you.